# Ssh into another virtual machine

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, puppet

Using vagrant I created 2 virtuals machines, one for puppet master and the other for the agent. I now need to automate the signing of certificates. I was considering using provisions to run shell scripts and ssh into specific virtual machines. Is this the right way to do this? Is there a better way to automate teh signing of pupper agent certificates? Sometimes when I attempted to ssh in Ive gotten a provising error where it states i need to use vagrant provision command.

Answer (score 1):

You could enable auto-signing on the puppet master.
On the puppet master edit the puppet.conf. Under [master] add `autosign = true`. This will accept any agent that talks to the master. This is regarded as being insecure.

To make it more secure; add the autosign config file which should be in `$confdir/autosign.conf`. This should include the sub/domains such as

```
  *.example.com
  *.local
```